# MS Access SQL Calculating values by date count

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

For school I'm doing a database of assassins and their hits. My teacher is on holidays and the replacement is at a loss of what to do, and no one else can help me...so Hoping you guys can..

I want a query I can use to make a report or form that will show a list of each assassin, their completed hits count, and their missed hits counts...

[image: How my database is laid out]

Completed hits have a DateCompleted entry and missed hits have no DateCompeted entry. Is this possible? How can I make it work? :)

The best we've come up with is very basic and doesn't do what I want (and it wont let us use GROUP BY or COUNT):

```
SELECT AssassinName, DateCompleted
FROM Assassins, Assignments
WHERE Assassins.AssassinID = Assignments.AssassinID;
```

Comment: What won't let you use group by or count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to use `count()`, you need an aggregation.  Second, you should be learning proper join syntax.  The rest is pretty obvious:

```
SELECT AssassinName, count(DateCompleted) as NumSuccesses,
       (count(*) - count(DateCompleted)) as NumMisses
FROM Assassins join
     Assignments
     on Assassins.AssassinID = Assignments.AssassinID
group by AssassinName
```

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thanks for responding. I don't have a "NumDateCompleted" so how would I get that to work? :)

I SHOULD be learning joins yes, but the teacher is away :(.

Comment: Nevermind blonde moment, I got it to work! Thanks so much :D.